# Adapt the width of an element in base of the content of another element (or div) next to it

Tags: html, css, box

I have two vertical divs, one to the left and one to the right. The left div contains text that ends after let's say half a page. I want to let my right div behave like this: fill the content on the right of the left div as long as the left div continues downwards. But when the left div ends the right div should fill the whole page. This is because the right div is much longer than the left div and I want to avoid that the right div continues narrowly after the left div ends and the user has to scroll down too much. Is there a way to archieve my goal?

Here is the current haml-code of the view:

```
%div.leftbox
  Here is the text in the leftbox
%div.rightbox
  Here is the much longer content of the right box
```

And my CSS is:

```
.leftbox {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  width: 485px;
}
.rightbox {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 70px 10px 8px;
  width: 355px;
}
```

Comment: Simply set `float:left` for your first element, remove `float:left` from the second one and the `display` property from both.

Comment: Unfortunately this puts the right div below the left div, not first aside and than below the left div when the left div has ended.

Comment: Well that might be due to the `width` and `margins` you have set, but in general it works that way, see http://jsfiddle.net/kwbh99jo/

Comment: You are right, after some trying it works :-)